# UWP WinRT: App is launching in background instead of foreground when using API Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am using API Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync  API to launch a target app from within another app using protocol. But the target app is launching in background instead of foreground. Anything I need to do to launch the app in the foreground?

```
    auto appUri = Windows::Foundation::Uri(m_appLaunchProtocolUrl);
    auto appStatus = co_await Windows::System::Launcher::QueryUriSupportAsync(appUri, Windows::System::LaunchQuerySupportType::Uri, m_appPackageFamilyName);
    if (appStatus == Windows::System::LaunchQuerySupportStatus::Available)
    {
        co_await Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchUriAsync(Windows::Foundation::Uri(appUri));
        handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you [handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#step-3-handle-the-activated-event) the activated event like this, then call [window active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63368610/7254781) method?

Comment: This is something we need to do in the target app. What if we do not own this app? Is this mandatory?

Comment: Is this really a UWP application, or are you calling this from a desktop application (using Win UI 3, for example)?

Comment: I am not sure about the target app. But the app from which I am making the call LaunchUriAsync is a UWP app.

Comment: Are you *positive* that this is a UWP application? If you are using Win UI 3, you aren't targeting the UWP. Are you?

Comment: ms-family: is the launch uri.

Comment: Let me give you details - I am using ProgressRing from Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace. Does that make it not target UWP?

Comment: WinUI 2 [`ProgressRing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.progressring?view=winui-2.7)  where under `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` could work in UWP platform. It does not related with above problem.  Are you positive that the target app has register protocol name correctly like document [said](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#step-1-specify-the-extension-point-in-the-package-manifest).

Comment: Yes, the name is correct. App is launching so name has to be correct right? It is just launching in background.

Comment: I am just not sure if they have handled the activated event. I am checking with them.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation#:~:text=details%20about%20icons.-,Step%203%3A%20Handle%20the%20activated%20event,-The%20OnActivated%20event

Comment: Target app is a win32 app not a UWP so  the document you shared is not applicable.

Comment: One observation - when I attach debugger to the source app, it launches the target app in foreground.

Comment: I tested with the target app (desktop-bridge app), it could launch by uri scheme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243638/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-rsp).